# Using xdm on fedora: Login Manager does not start on boot, manually starting does not open the window manager

Tags: fedora, systemd, x11, xdm

I'm trying to install a Fedora 30 system from the ground up. I want to use i3 as my Window Manager and xdm as my login manager.
I can start an X server manually with `startx`, which starts i3. I then tried to start xdm on boot by doing `sudo systemctl enable xdm`, but xdm does not start on boot, I only get a non-graphic login. If I start xdm manually, it works, but it does not start the window manager but returns to the login screen, even after a successfull login.
When I look in the journal, I find the following lines

```
PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib64/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so): /usr/lib64/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so: cannot open shared file: No such file or direcory
PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib64/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

I set up an `.xsession`. Please ask in the comments for more details (logs, config,...), I'm not sure weather something is helpful here or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to to two things: make `.xsession` executable and run `systemctl set-default graphical.target`.